# Questions on persisting elements with relations

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I usually see examples of entities that are being persisted on the net using JPA but it only involves one entity.  But I can't get myself to understand if there are relations involve.

Now example, I have a many to one mapping between Professor and Department.

```
@Entity
public class Professor {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
    private Department department;
}
@Entity
public class Department {
    //normal getters and setters
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Now, in my JSF page.. I usually add mapping between my form elements
and my managed bean.
During add operation, in a web UI you would usually show a drop down box of departments
when adding new professor.

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.currentProf.name}"/>
.
. /* other mappings here */
.
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.currentProf.department.name}>
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.allDepartments}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{myBean.handleSave}" />
```

Now, my question is:  Is it a requirement to get the department first then set it to my current
professor property before persisting it?
Because in my case, I have already set the department name but not the department Id..

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean{
    public Professor currentProf;
    public BusinessService service;
    public String handleSave(){
        Department dept = service.findDepartment(currentProf.getDepartment().getName());
        currentProf.setDepartment(dept);
        service.createProfessor(currentProf);
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getAllDepartments(){
        return service.getAllDepartments();
    }
}
```

I just show my business service here for clarity.

```
public class BusinessService {
  protected EntityManager em;

  public Professor createProfessor(Professor prof) {
    em.persist(prof);
    return prof;
  }
}
```

Many examples on the net shows rough example such as this:

```
Department dept = new Department();
dept.setId(1);
dept.setName("Finance");
Prof newProf = new Professor();
newProf.setDepartment(dept);
service.createProfessor(newProf);
```

But I think that this is not how data is presented and gathered in a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loaded Department entity object (or a reference to it's proxy) in order to be able link it to the Professor. Just having the Department name does not give you a reference to the entity object.

Look at this reference from the [Hibernate documentation, Chapter 3: 3.3. Loading an object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1061):

You can either load the object state with:

```
dept = em.find(Department.class, deptId);
```

or just get the reference to it:

```
dept = em.getReference(Department.class, deptId);  // no db hit
```

But yes, you do need to retrieve the Department object (or its proxy reference) if you want to link it to the Professor. Hibernate manages the entire object state, its links to other entities, so it's not possible to just use name for you to link a Professor to a Department.

If you don't have the id, just the name of the Department, then you need to do it like you did it in your code (query for Department through name).

Comment: Hi, I am not actually persisting the Department coz it is already enrolled. I just wanted to know If I need to retrieve the Department from DB first then set it to my Professor Class. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you already have a detached entity object Department, you can just set Department to Professor and merge it into the Persistence Context. I will edit my answer later this evening to clarify.